# IntelliJ not recognizing breakpoints when debugging android application

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-viewpager, breakpoints

I am trying to debug an application using IntelliJ IDEA 12.04. I set a breakpoint on a line. However, when I hit the *run* button the application still force closes. It does not stop at the line that I selected as the breakpoint. What's causing that to occur?

This the error I am experiencing.

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at see.submit.solve.ui.CarouselActivity.onCreate(CarouselActivity.java:41)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
```

This is where the error is occuring.

```
 pager.setAdapter(new BootstrapPagerAdapter(getResources(), getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

I was trying to set a breakpoint at this line of code to ensure that the ViewPager was actually being passed to *pager*.

```
    @InjectView(id.vp_pages) ViewPager pager;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use *debug*, not *run*. Run doesn't attach the debugger.

[image]